# My code stops working and no error appears

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

My code is stopped and no error occurs when I comment out the code of  //adding address and select from the suggestion bar here I'm selecting with ID then it works but when I want to run the program without commenting it's not working. And I'm facing this issue in every of my program. sometimes when I moved the code from line 13 to 25 it starts working.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://ss-superadmin-staging.labaiik.net/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("arsalan.hameed@avrioc.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("admin");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Login')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        
        //in the superadmin now use java script executor
        JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[13]/a[1]"));
        je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
        System.out.println(element.getText());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[13]/a[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[13]/ul[1]/li[1]/a[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Pending Approval')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btnStickUpSizeToggler']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='restaurantName_0']")).sendKeys("Automation Testing Restaurant");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
       
        
        
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='internalRestaurantName']")).sendKeys("Testing Restaurant AUT");
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Pimage']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Faizan\\Desktop\\dummy products images\\bambou.png");
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Bimage']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Faizan\\Desktop\\dummy products images\\maxresdefault.jpg");
                 
         
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='phone']")).sendKeys("3453221447");
    
               //adding email address
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("faizantest@test.com");
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               
               //now adding the billing address
              driver.findElement(By.id("entityAddress_01")).sendKeys("Khalifa city sector 13");
              Thread.sleep(4000);
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            List <WebElement> suggestions;
            suggestions =driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item-query"));
            if(suggestions != null)
            {
                for (WebElement suggests : suggestions) {
                    //System.out.println(suggests.getText());
                    if(suggests.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Khalifa city"));
                    suggests.click();
                    break;
                }       
                    
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='contact_person_name']")).sendKeys("Faizan");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("123456");
                
                
                   //adding address and select from the suggestion bar here I'm selecting with ID
                    driver.findElement(By.id("entityAddress_0")).sendKeys("Khalifa city sector 13");
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    List <WebElement> suggestion = driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item")); //here I print all the value which are coming 
 
                   //here I'm using for each loop and print the value so we can see all the value which appeared in suggestions
                    for (WebElement suggest : suggestion) {
                    if(suggest.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Sector 13Khalifa City - Abu Dhabi - United Arab Emirates")) {
                   suggest.click();
                   
                  break;}
               //Thread.sleep(4000);
              
               //here selecting the cuisine from the dropdown
              
               WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='primary_cuisine']"));
               Select sel = new Select(element1);
               sel.selectByVisibleText("fxn1");
               
               
            
          driver.quit();
               }}
```

}}

below is the console.

Starting ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61 (418b78f5838ed0b1c69bb4e51ea0252171854915-refs/branch-heads/4606@{#1204}) on port 6178
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Oct 15, 2021 3:04:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What code do you mean on line 13 that you move to 25 that works? Can you be specific? What do you mean this code "stops"? What does "not working" mean? What does "facing this issue in every one of your programs" mean? Why do you have an `implicitWait()` in the middle of your code but 10+ `Thread.sleeps()`?

Comment: I was just giving an example that if I comment any code from line 13 the below code will run but if i want to run the whole program it doesn't run it stops.